# Linkable tabs with history - Back button problem

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs, history, back

I need your help, I would like to have tabs linkable, for the moment it works very well, the problem is for the history: when we click on the back button of the browser, the address changes well, but the tab does not turn on ...
(I use jQuery and boostrap)

html:

```html
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tpl-tabs animate">
      <li class="active"> <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a> </li>
    </ul>
```

JS: (added to make linkable tabs)

```
var hash = document.location.hash;
var prefix = "tab_";

if(hash){
    $(".nav-tabs a[href=" + hash.replace(prefix, "") + "]").tab("show");
        }

$(".nav-tabs a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e){
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#","#" + prefix);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would go with the `onhashchange` listener here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

or if you want to create a more robust solution I would use the content from this article:

http://www.redotheweb.com/2012/05/17/enable-back-button-handling-with-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-plugin.html

where you can find how to use History API properly

Comment: Thank you for your reply !
I think it seems to work, I made a mixture of the two codes to avoid scroller to the ID when we use the history, and in order to make a direct link on a tab specific.
It is certainly not very clean because I am beginner but it works !

Answer (score 1):

@tartartartar

Thank you for coming back and posting your final solution! I've been trying to get linkable tabs to function properly for me. Your "mixture" code worked great, except for making the first tab active if there's no hash, and using the back button if there's no hash. I'm using .active classes so that may have made a difference. To make the first tab active if no hash I added an `else` statement after the first `if` statement:

```
var prefix = "tab_";
var hash = document.location.hash;
if(hash){
   $(".nav-tabs a[href=" + hash.replace(prefix, "") + "]").tab("show");
} else {
   $('.nav-tabs a:first').addClass('active');
  }
```

The following code worked for using the back button, until there wasn't a hash (`index.html` vs `index.html#tab_blue`):

```
function locationHashChanged() {
  var activeTab = $("[href=" + document.location.hash.replace(prefix,"") + "]");
  if (activeTab.length) {
    activeTab.tab('show');
  } else {
      $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');
    }
}
window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

After setting up an `alert(activeTab.length);` just before the `if` statement I noticed that it would return "1" for hash and "4" for no hash, so I added an identity operator `===` to check for the value. I also added a `.removeClass` to make sure there weren't two active tabs at the same time:

```
if (activeTab.length === 1) {
  activeTab.tab('show');
} else {
    $('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-content ul').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav-tabs li:first').addClass('active');
    $('.tab-content ul:first').addClass('active');
  }
}
window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mkbctrl for your reply ! I think it seems to work, I made a mixture of the two codes to avoid scroller to the ID when we use the history, and in order to make a direct link on a tab specific. It is certainly not very clean because I am beginner but it works !

```
var prefix = "tab_";
var hash = document.location.hash;
if(hash){
        $(".nav-tabs a[href=" + hash.replace(prefix, "") + "]").tab("show");
    }

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function() {
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href').replace("#","#" + prefix));
    });

    function locationHashChanged() {
            var activeTab = $("[href=" + document.location.hash.replace(prefix,"") + "]");
            if (activeTab.length) {
                activeTab.tab('show');
            } else {
              $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');
            }
        }
    window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

I removed this from bootstrap.css because I had a display problem using the history:

```
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
/*background-color:#eee; Removed*/
```

}

So, Thank you so much !